# Issue in displaying webpage in IE11 in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ie11

I am able to input the username, the password, and then click on the login button, but after clicking on the login button it displays nothing on webpage in IE11 but works fine with Chrome and Firefox.

Could you please help me what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Does the same happen if you just click the login button yourself ? Is it really something do with Selenium.

Comment: I think its browser compatibility issue with ie11. Now It doesn't work manually nor automation. When I run my testng suite, it opens ie11 browser with blank page and my test case fail. I am stuck with ie11.

Comment: @SlightlyKosumi Now its totally crashed. Launches the browser but does not display anything. Looks like IE compatible issue.

Answer (score 0):

IE has quircks with clicks, sometimes the first click is not effective and looks as if it does nothing. First I try to `Click()` twice on the element. If that works, it is probably a focus issue, where the first click focusses the button. Try to focus something else first.

I would also try this [answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/9507/3201).

Answer (score 0):

IE has a drawback sometimes even you try to perform .click() it does not work there are 2 reasons behind this.

1. If this IE11 try to get the latest version of IEdriver from selenium hq
2. If #1 does not solve your issue. Then instead of click() try using sendkeys(keys.enter).

Thanks